# How to get this applescript working?

Tags: node.js, applescript, osx-yosemite, automator, url-shortener

So the goal of this little diversion is to be able to select a piece of text containing a URL and have OS X convert it to a short URL using the goo.gl URL shortener service.

To that end I have created a service using Automator that accepts text input and passes that input to a "Run AppleScript" action.  The AppleScript is listed below.

I've installed node.js v0.10.33 and also installed a node package called json (http://trentm.com/json/)

The script below works fine as long as I don't pipe the output to the json node app.
The curl command *with piping to the json node app* works perfect in Terminal.

My guess is something with the shell environment is off, but I have no idea how to look into that.
Any help?

```
-- shorten URLs via goo.gl URL shortener
-- syntax derrived from Scott Lowe @ blog.scottlowe.org

on run {input, parameters}

    set curlCommand to "curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"longUrl\": \"" & input & "\"}' | /usr/local/bin/json id"

    set jsonResult to (do shell script curlCommand)

    return jsonResult
end run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great tool for handling JSON in Applescript is the free App JSON Helper (App Store). It converts JSON to Applescript dictionaries. So my answer is very (very) similar to @regulus6633 post, but without text parsing the JSON:

```
set input to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757656/how-to-get-this-applescript-working"

-- Note: without piping to grep at the end!
set curlCommand to "curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"longUrl\": \"" & input & "\"}'"

-- getting the full JSON answer
set jsonResult to do shell script curlCommand

-- using JSON Helper to translate JSON to Applescript dictionary
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set shortURL to |id| of (read JSON from jsonResult)
end tell

return shortURL
```

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this out.  For my own edification I'd like to know why the version I wrote doesn't work - but I can hack around with that when I have *much* more time :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have "return curlCommand"? Don't you really want "return jsonResult"?

Admittedly I don't know anything about json but the result of the curl command is a string and I do know how to parse a string in applescript. Here's how I would write your code parsing it as a string. Note I used this webpage's url as "input"...

```
set input to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757656/how-to-get-this-applescript-working"

set curlCommand to "curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"longUrl\": \"" & input & "\"}' | grep '\"id\"'"
set jsonResult to do shell script curlCommand
set shortURL to text 9 thru -2 of jsonResult
return shortURL
```

Comment: appologies for the confusion.  You are correct, I do want to return jsonResult.  I was returning curlCommand as part of my debugging process and forgot to change it back.